# How to move class based on attribute

Tags: javascript

I am building a slider and can not figure out how to move classes from the 1st three children, to the next and so on..

I'm trying to move the active class to the next 'data-group'

```
<ul>
    <li class="active" data-group="1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="active" data-group="1">Item 2</li>
    <li class="active" data-group="1">Item 3</li>
    <li data-group="2">Item 4</li>
    <li data-group="2">Item 5</li>
    <li data-group="2">Item 6</li>
    <li data-group="3">Item 7</li>
    <li data-group="3">Item 8</li>
    <li data-group="3">Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

I've got a event listener attached to prev/next buttons. Just not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Mind pasting your code?

Comment: @IlanP No no, that's not how SO works. Questions need to stand on their own.

Comment: Plain JS, or jQuery, or...? Basically you need to query based on `data-group`, and either remove `active` from everything and add to the next group, or remove from the current group and add to the next group.

Comment: @DaveNewton ah gotcha, figured it would be easier if I can get the OP to put what he has up so I can see it ;/

Comment: @IlanP it would indeed be easier to help the OP if we can get them to put up their code, but please don't encourage people to post code on 3rd party sites. Questions which don't include the relevant code within the question body itself can be marked as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (since those external links can change or die over time, making the question much less useful to others). And besides, there's really nothing stopping OP from pasting it straight into here. What's the need for another tool?

Comment: @IlanP there are built in code snippet tools. Please do not use pastebin or external sources where possible since dead links make questions invalid.

Comment: Got you guys; was just trying to help; points noted

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to posting. I'm trying to do this with plain JavaScript.

Basically, for the slider with one item on screen, I'm just querying the one active slide

Comment: @AndrewPittman please post your JavaScript attempt so far, thanks. Then we can hopefully adapt it to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of logic and you can move your active values by looking at your data by getting the attribute `data-group` and doing some calculations with it:

```js
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', e => {

  // Get the max group number
  let max = Math.max(...[...document.querySelectorAll(`[data-group]`)].map(el => parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-group'))));

  // Get the current group
  let group = parseInt(document.querySelector('.active').getAttribute('data-group'));
  
  // Remove the active attribute
  [...document.querySelectorAll(`[data-group="${group}"]`)].forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
  
  // Increment the group then compare if the group value is larger than the max 
  // If it is set the group to 1
  if(++group > max) group = 1;

  // Add the active class to the proper group
  [...document.querySelectorAll(`[data-group="${group}"]`)].forEach(el => el.classList.add('active'));

})
```

```css
.active {color:red;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active" data-group="1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="active" data-group="1">Item 2</li>
  <li class="active" data-group="1">Item 3</li>
  <li data-group="2">Item 4</li>
  <li data-group="2">Item 5</li>
  <li data-group="2">Item 6</li>
  <li data-group="3">Item 7</li>
  <li data-group="3">Item 8</li>
  <li data-group="3">Item 9</li>
</ul>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
let current = null;

// Remove class from current active elements
document.querySelectorAll('.active').forEach(i => {
   //Get the current group if unknown
   if (!current) {
        current = i.getAttribute('data-group');
   }

   i.classList.remove('active');
});

// Get the next group
current = parseInt(current) + 1;

// Add class to next group's elements
document.querySelectorAll(`li[data-group="${current}"]`).forEach(i => {
   i.classList.add('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its mor easy if you use id and set a class or style for id ex. (getElementForId).

```
<ul>
<li data-group="1" id="item1">Item 1</li>
<li data-group="1" id="item2">Item 2</li>
<li data-group="1" id="item3">Item 3</li>
<li data-group="2" id="item4">Item 4</li>
<li data-group="2" id="item5">Item 5</li>
<li data-group="2" id="item6">Item 6</li>
<li data-group="3" id="item7">Item 7</li>
<li data-group="3" id="item8">Item 8</li>
<li data-group="3" id="item9">Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

then create a function for 
    document.getElementById(the_id_to_change).style.property = new style

like

```
<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">
Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the li's and then check if the attribute is according to your preference, For each element of the li which has the attribute `data-group`. We check if the attribute's value is equal to what we want. Then we add the class as active, else we remove the class. Use `Array.prototype.slice.call(allLi)` to convert the nodeList to an array.

Add a button too, with an incrementing value, so your code becomes

```js
let i = 1;
document.querySelector('#next').addEventListener("click", () => {
  i++
  let allLi = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-group]'); // get all li with the attribute data-group
  Array.prototype.slice.call(allLi).forEach((elem, _) => { // for every li element
    if (elem.getAttribute("data-group") == i) { // check if the attribute = the value we want on one click
      elem.classList.add("active") // add to the element's class
    } else {
      elem.classList.remove("active") // or else, remove the element's class
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active" data-group="1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="active" data-group="1">Item 2</li>
  <li class="active" data-group="1">Item 3</li>
  <li data-group="2">Item 4</li>
  <li data-group="2">Item 5</li>
  <li data-group="2">Item 6</li>
  <li data-group="3">Item 7</li>
  <li data-group="3">Item 8</li>
  <li data-group="3">Item 9</li>
</ul>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will return a list of all elements that match a given query.  you can use it like this:

```
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('[data-group="2"]')) {
  element.classlist.add('active')
}
```

You will of course need to do something similar to remove the previous "active" classes. That might look something like this:

```
// Run BEFORE switching to data-group 2
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.active')) {
  element.sclassList.remove('active')
}
```